# how to stop application's background threads under WebSphere

Tags: java, multithreading, websphere

We are deploying application in WebSphere cluster. Application is running his own never terminated threads that are checking some condition for example:

```
while(true){
  logger.severe("Unterminated thread");
  Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Problem is that after the application is stop(via wsadmin or admin console) in the WebSphere, only the servlets are unregistrated but
these threads are not kill and are still running. Is there any way how to kill this treads when i am stopping the application? We are using WebSphere 7.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments to another answer, I have a suggestion.  (Note, I agree with Oleg that you really shouldn't be doing it this way, but if you must...).

I presume that in the regular Java application that this code is from, these background threads somehow receive a signal to stop.  What I would suggest is using a [`ServletContextListener`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to send the stop signal when your servlets have all been deregistered.

Note that if you don't already have some way to tell the threads to stop, that's probably *another* bug, and this won't help at all.

Comment: Really thanks, this look like fastest way how to fix the application.

Comment: Hi! But imagine that the application is already deployed and running and you don't want to stop the server, but do need to terminate the hanging threads. Is it possible?

Comment: @ACosta, unless you already have some mechanism to tell those threads to stop, then as far as I'm aware no, you can't just "go in" somewhere and stop them.

Comment: I had to run Terminate in websphere Admin Console on the server in which the application was installed, or else I wouldn't be able to stop it!

Answer (score 6):

You should never manually create threads from JavaEE application. Thread management is something that should be provided by JavaEE container.

WebSphere has a WorkManager mechanism to assist you with you threading needs. Please look at [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0606_johnson/0606_johnson.html) for implementation details.

Comment: Hello yes, i understand problem is that it was not expecting that it will be running in application container and it has been written as a normal java application.